# request has file is not working - laravel

Tags: laravel

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        return "this is if";
    } else {
        return 'this is else';
    }
}
```

This is my function. The print is "this is else".  Why it's not going inside if?

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    dd($request);
}
```

It is giving us:

[image]

```
public function store(Request $request) {
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

It is giving us:

[image]

So, I'm taking an 'image', but the `hasFile` function does not see it. How to fix it?

Extra: This is my form section:

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route('articles.store')  }} " enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Category</label>
        <select name="category" required>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Article Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Article Content</label>
        <textarea name="contentArticle" id="summernote"  rows="12"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Create an Article</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: are you using nay middleware.code looks good.if you are using middleware then can you show code

Comment: files should be in the files key. do you get any file there??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `enctype` in your frontend code, there is not any problem just run the below commands:

```
composer dump-autoload

php artisan optimize:clear
```

If again that does not work then use the below code for checking if you have an image or not:

```
if ($request->file('image')!=null){...}
```

In place of:

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){...}
```

Comment: Yes its working, but why its not working with hasFile? Do you have any idea

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: No, sorry im the new in Laravel

Comment: Run that cmd command and check your code is working or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you try to do this ?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

       dd($request->all());
    {
```

What result do you get ?